# How do I convert a VDI HDD to a VHD file?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vhd, virtual-drive, vdi

Is there a way to convert a VDI HDD to a VHD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is to use VBoxmanage [as explained by Derek P](https://superuser.com/questions/69351/convert-vdi-to-vhd/110039#110039). If you have an old VirtualBox, either upgrade, or:

You [convert VDI to VMDK](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/197423), then convert VMDK to VHD in one of several ways:

1. VMWare VCenter Converter Standalone Client
2. [vmToolkits VMDK to VHD converter](http://vmtoolkit.com/files/folders/converters/entry8.aspx)
3. [WinImage](http://www.winimage.com/) (shareware)

Comment: how would i convert the VMDK to VHD?

Comment: This is a horrible way of doing it, look at the posts below for a better way.

Comment: @cc0, you're right.  Back when I wrote this though, VBoxManage didn't support vdi to vhd, just the other way around. Derek P's answer is better.

Comment: And vmtoolkit.com is up for sale.

Answer (score 73):

This function is built into VirtualBox:

```
VBoxManage clonehd source.vdi target.vhd --format vhd
```

Comment: what if that fails (silently) with %ERRORLEVEL% being -1073741819 ?

Answer (score 14):

There is a new option now in VirtualBox 4.1 to copy a VDI with a new format (including VHD), which is equivalent to the command Derek P pointed out last year, but in a nice GUI.

1. Open Virtual Box and select Files > Virtual Media Manager.
2. Select an existing disk file on the Hard Disks tab and click the Copy button.
3. Complete the steps in the wizard. Select VHD when prompted for the file type.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as Derek said, builtin tool with VirtualBox works well under Windows OS without any third party software. Converted OS is booting without any troubles, for more information with example steps check this post,

[VDI to VHD – Convert VirtualBox Virtual Machines to Virtual PC](http://www.sysprobs.com/vdi-vhd-convert-virtualbox-virtual-machines-virtual-pc)

Answer (score 4):

Without downloading and installing VirtualBox, you can use qemu-img from QEMU package:

```
qemu-img.exe convert source.img -O vhdx -o subformat=dynamic dest.vhdx
```

Download for windows:
https://cloudbase.it/qemu-img-windows/

Comment: This is a far better answer than using downloaded tools, as qemu-img already exists in WSL.