# Creating physical machine from a virtual one

Tags: virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to convert virtual machines to physical environments?](https://superuser.com/questions/114445/is-it-possible-to-convert-virtual-machines-to-physical-environments)

I've come across the question on [creating a virtual machine in VirtualBox from a physical one](https://serverfault.com/questions/33603/creating-a-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox-from-a-physical-one). Is it possible to do the opposite: to create a physical installation from a virtual machine? (Let's assume that the physical hardware matches the virtual one.)

Comment: It seems like it might be easier to get virtualbox running transparently in a lightweight distro like Arch ...

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible--possibly using your favorite disk imaging software to create a disk image of the VM, then deploying it on the physical hardware.

In reality, the complexity of this task will likely depend greatly on the OS you're trying to move.

Answer (score 0):

The process of converting a physical machine to virtual basically is essentially the same when going from virtual to physical.  Any product that supports P2V should also support V2P with the possible exception of dedicated tools by MS/VMWare (and other Virtualization system vendors) where the intention is to get you to use their virtualization product - not help you move AWAY from their virtualization product.