# Migrate Windows 8 from VirtualBox to partition

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, virtualbox, migration

I had severe problems with installing Windows 7 and 8 which I didn't get fixed after a lot of research. So I am trying a new approach!

I now have a Windows 8 up and running in a VirtualBox on my Ubuntu. I made myself a raw ".img" of that virtual system using "VBoxManage clonehd file.vdi output.img --format RAW" (see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/114445/is-it-possible-to-convert-virtual-machines-to-physical-environments) thread for more info). The plan was to use "dd if=system.img of=/dev/sda" next but while this does not throw an error, the partition is always damaged afterwards. Damaged in a way that I could neither revive it with testdisk nor with ntfsfix. I also tried FAT32 as a partition type which gave me the same result.

Is there an error in my logic?

Using Clonezilla or Acronis True Image don't really seem logical to me, since this is something that should be done right from my OS since it isn't affected?!

It has been recommended to make the partition the same size as the image but how would I ensure that?

Comment: Are the VirtualBox image and the partition the same size?

Comment: Almost, I made the partition about 10% larger, just in case.

Comment: Someone else should correct me of this is wrong, but I suspect the drives have to be identical if you are going to do a block-level copy like this.

Comment: I would try that, but how exact does it have to be? Would it be enough to check the partitions size with fdisk?
Also I just noticed that there are two partitions in ".img" file... How do I account for that?