# Create an ISO image from a virtual device image

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, iso-image

## Oracle VM -> ISO

I am using Oracles VM VirtualBox to good effect and have created several ubuntu machines created from an ISO image.

My question is that I now want to go from a VM machine to a real machine and would love to be able to take an ISO image of the virtual machine to deploy onto a number of physical devices that will be a standalone **appliance** and **not** connected on the internet.

If not ISO then what else is there I can use to create and load an image?

Thanks in advance.

Assistance appreciated.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers on the super user stack exchange.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/114445/is-it-possible-to-convert-virtual-machines-to-physical-environments/

Answer (score 1):

you can use items such as clonezilla to take an "image" of the machine which can then be deployed onto other machines:

Site:
http://clonezilla.org/

Simply put this takes a snapshot of your virtual machine which can then be "pasted" onto a hardware configuration.

For a windows image a SYSPREP command will have to be run, no idea for Ubuntu based bachines.

This should work without too much hassle though besides installing the relevant drivers for the hardware configurations you are pushing this image on.

Regards,