# Converting VirtualBox VM to Main OS?

Tags: windows-7, macos, hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running Windows 7 on my main machine, however I have installed Mac OS X Mavericks to a VirtualBox VM (on another hard drive) which I am tend to be using a fair bit.

The VM is fully setup and working, and I want to make the OS X VM as my main OS, so when I boot up my PC, it will boot into my Mavericks OS instead of Windows.

My plan is to use the hard drive that already has Mavericks installed, and put it into my PC, so effectively I have one hard drive in my machine that is running Mavericks.

Is there any way to convert a VDI (Virtual Disk Image) to run as a Primary OS? If any of this even makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldnt have thought this would be possible as you need VB to boot the disk image, though I am not 100% sure and will be interested to see the answer to this. Interesting question.

Comment: Isn't running a Mac OS on a non-Mac physical machine a license violation?

Comment: Ashley - I thought you could just extract the VDI and use it without VirtualBox, surely there is a converter for it somewhere online?

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers you can check out:

[Is it possible to convert virtual machines to physical environments?](https://superuser.com/questions/114445/is-it-possible-to-convert-virtual-machines-to-physical-environments)

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/convert-vm-iso

> Acronis TrueImage is a commercial (but inexpensive) professional tool for making disk image backups. You can find it on Amazon. It provides various options but the option you want is whole disk backup. TrueImage comes on a bootable setup CD. You boot your VM off that, and back up your VMs drive to a real USB drive. You can then go to a real PC, boot that PC off the same CD, and restore the backup from the USB drive onto the hard drive of that PC. And that's it, V2P procedure completed.

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=40124#wrap

Comment: Had a change of plan - since this has just been installed, I can always start a fresh installation, no problem. If I was to burn the ISO to a USB stick or something, and boot from it - download Mavericks then get it to run off the Hard Drive like a normal OS - surely this would work?