# How to prepare custom Ubuntu image on Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, iso-image

I would like to prepare Ubuntu bootable ISO image so I can boot it from USB pendrive. I want to the image to contain also some additional software, e.g., VLC for playing movies.

Can I prepare such updated image using VirtualBox hosted on Windows? How?

I would like to avoid installing the image on real hardware, hence the idea of using VirtualBox. [I've read](https://superuser.com/a/114452/106160) converting VDI file to ISO will not result in a image that I can boot from CD/USB.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the offical Ubuntu [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) (or [InstallCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization)) guide within an Ubuntu VM. You can also use the 3rd party [customizer](https://github.com/kamilion/customizer) tool.

(The full instructions for the LiveCDCustomization are rather long, so I'm just posting the section headers here as a general overview.)

1. Install pre-requisities
2. Obtain the base system
3. Extract the CD .iso contents
4. Extract the Desktop system
5. Prepare and chroot
6. **Customizations**
7. Cleanup
8. Producing the CD image