# From VirtualBox VM (.vdi file) to a USB bootable ISO image

Tags: usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bootable-media, dd

I have set up a virtual machine with Xubuntu Linux in VirtualBox.

The disk is 4.5 GB a .vdi file.

How can I make an IMG or ISO file from this, such that I can then write it into a bootable USB flash drive,

- either with Rufus disk imager software (on Windows)
- or with `dd if=myvm.img of=/dev/sdc`

?

**TL;DR: I'm searching for a `convert-vmdisk myvm.vdi myvm-bootable.img` tool.**

---

I've already tried answers from [Is it possible to convert virtual machines to physical environments?](https://superuser.com/questions/114445/is-it-possible-to-convert-virtual-machines-to-physical-environments) and especially

```
VBoxManage internalcommands converttoraw file.vdi output.img
```

but then after writing this .img to a USB flash drive (with Rufus), the PC won't boot on this USB flash drive.

Linked topic: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=40124

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few number of attempts, finally this works:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands converttoraw file.vdi output.img
```

Then Rufus to write it to a USB flash drive or external USB HDD.

Initially, I couldn't boot this device on computer startup.

Reason: my BIOS was set up on "UEFI only". I switched this parameter to "Both (UEFI and Legacy)", and "Legacy first". Then it works!

Comment: Converted .vmdk to .img.
Copied .img to USB flash drive via dd.
Doesn't boot on a Lenovo T430 (with UEFI disabled or enabled in BIOS).

As data point: When putting Ubuntu 22.04 on same USB flash drive via unetbootin, it does boot on same laptop.