# Is there a tool to convert VHD images to VDI images?

Tags: virtual-machine, vhd, virtual-drive, vdi

I saw the response for [converting VDI images into VHD images](https://superuser.com/questions/69351/convert-vdi-to-vhd), but I want to do the opposite conversion - is there a tool to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Adapting one of those answers, you could use VBoxManage:

> VBoxManage clonehd source.vhd target.vdi --format vdi

If you are just looking to use the vhd in Virtualbox, you do not need to convert it yourself, Virtualbox will quite happily use a vhd image. You can just add it to the list of disks in "Virtual Media Manager".

Comment: this only works reliably for VHD files from Virtual PC, not for VHD files created using Hyper-V

Comment: It works for vmdk files too.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to convert VHD to VDI because when you need to periodically compact the VHD to recover space, you cannot use VBoxManage to compact. You will have to use the virtual PC disk wizard to compact otherwise.