# Boot natively from a Virtual Box installation

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed in Virtualbox. The VB installation image is around 4gb(.vdi file). I dont wish to reinstall Ubuntu and then install everything all over again.

Can I  boot natively using this image?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a recent version Windows as your host system...

You can convert the .vdi file to a .vhd file (this is a Microsoft virtual hard drive. You can convert the file using the command line [VBoxmanage.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/69351/convert-vdi-to-vhd) tool. Virtualbox will quite happily use the vhd file if you replace the vdi file with the vhd file for the virtual machine).

You can then add the resultant vhd file to the Windows boot menu using either  [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) or the [tool that comes with Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799299%28WS.10%29.aspx).

(The TechNet link also explains how to install the Windows 7 bootloader on an older version of Windows.)

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work. OS inside VHD needs to be aware of this booting and so far only Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 can be booted from inside of VHD. All other OS (including even older versions of Windows) will just hang there.

Comment: Exactly as said by @JosipMedved, it will never work.